# Global var could not be reset in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a simple script:

```
    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var img; 
    var img_width = 0; 
    var img_height = 0;
    var f = $(this)[0].files[0];  
    if (f != null) {
      if (f.type == 'image/jpeg') {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
          img_width = this.width;  //why not $(this)??
          img_height = this.height;
          alert(img_width + ' x ' + img_height);  //1st alert
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(f);
        alert(img_width + ' x ' + img_height); //2nd alert
      };
    };
```

The `img_width` & `img_height` are a global var and its value is reset with `img.onload`. When the script is executed, the `first alert` displays the width and height. However the `2nd alert` always displays `0 x 0`. Why the gloabl var `img_width` and `img_height` were not reset within `img.onload` for late use in main thread?

Comment: It won't work because the `onload` will be fired asynchronously

Comment: @user938363 The duplicate answer link is spot on. `onload` is an asynchronous call which does not execute inline. It executes after the image has completed it's load. Since the second `alert` is inline with the "main thread", after the onload function is set and is waiting to be triggered, the code continues on, calling the second alert before the image finishes. When the load fires off, the onload function is executed, and the first alert is called.

Comment: How to reset the value of img_width and img_height for late use in main thread?